# Why my vscode is not showing indent while I press enter in brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know the reason but my vscode is not working properly

because whenever i press enter in bracket it automatically add indent and this beautifies the code but i don't know why it's stopped now

Expected

```
if(--------) {
    Statement 1
}
```

Actual

```
if(------) {
Statement 1}
```

[Editor:Indent-auto detailed screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxEcN.png)

[Editor:Intent-auto screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOyY5.png)

Comment: what if you switch your auto indent setting to "full"?

Comment: i changed it to advance, what should I change it too?

Comment: How should I know? You haven't even specified what programming language (extension) you're using. Just try changing it to each value and observe the resulting behaviour and report back what you find.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must have messed up the settings
There are two things you shud try doing

```
Try checking the indentation settings
```

> Open your VSCode settings by pressing Ctrl + ,
> Search for "Auto Indent".
> Make sure the option for <Editor:Auto Indent> is enabled.

```
If you are beginner try setting the vs code settings to default preferences
```

> Open the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P
> Go to "Preferences
> Click the three dots and choose "Reset to Defaults"

Comment: what's up with the weird formatting?

Comment: it doesn't help me

Comment: Please refer to the screenshot

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, it was working fine, but, recently it turned out like yours only.

First set auto indent to full in VS Code Settings. (idk if that helps or not just do it)

My problem was not solved by this alone.
Go to `settings.json` then search for `editor.language.brackets`
Remove this key from the settings.json and your problem will be solved.

Comment: It also fixes the bracket color issue